# Vue make last item in list call function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a menu with some elements and I want the last element `logout` to call a function i have defined in my methods section called `logout()`. The first two elements are intended to route to different routes in my application.  How can I achieve this?

What I have tried:

```
data() {
  return {
    loggedIn: false,
    menuItems: [
      { title: "Cats", route: "cats" },
      { title: "Dogs", route: "dogs" },
      { title: "Logout", route: "/"}
    ]
  };
},
```

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-item
    v-for="(item, index) in menuItems"
    :key="index"
    :to="item.route"
    @click="item.title === 'Logout' ? {logout} : {}"
  >
    <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `@click="item.title === 'Logout' && logout()"`?

Comment: boom. that worked. nice thing to know going forward

Comment: You probably want to prevent the default event handling too so perhaps `@click="item.title === 'Logout' && $event.preventDefault() && logout()"` (or something like that)

Comment: I think you could just do `@click.prevent` to prevent the default event handling.

Comment: @Sanjay but OP wants the non-logout links to work as normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably implement this along these lines:

Add an optional `action` property in your menuItems objects that will invoke a defined function.

```
data() {
  return {
    loggedIn: false,
    menuItems: [
      { title: "Cats", route: "cats" },
      { title: "Dogs", route: "dogs" },
      {
        title: "Logout",
        route: "/",
        action: () => this.methods.logout() // invoke logout method here
      }
    ]
  };
},
```

Then in your v-for, you can simply check it the action property exists, and if it does, invoke it.

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-item
    v-for="(item, index) in menuItems"
    :key="index"
    :to="item.route"
    @click="item.action && item.action()"
  >
    <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

This way, your solution is scalable and your template logic is decoupled from any specific menu item.